# i need to find logic to add new table for sequelize in node js

Tags: sequelize.js

user table

id: 1 , name: messi;

id: 2 , name: Alex;

room table

id 1, name: song;

id: 2, name: game;

chat data

userId:  2, first_seen: 1671471509, roomId: 1;

userId:  2, first_seen: 1671471510, roomId: 1;

userId:  2, first_seen: 167147151, roomId: 2;

new table I want to create this

userId:  2, first_seen: 1671471509, last_seen: 167147151, roomId: 1;

Alex was in the singing room on 1671471509. He was in the singing room on 1671471510, he was in the game room on 167147151.

Alex seen for the first time in the singing room 1671471509,

that was the last time he was seen 167147151,

because when he moved to another room, the previous room was seen for the last time.

I want to create a new table and print the first and last seen of users in the room

how can I do that?

Comment: These are 2 questions: 1. the models for the task 2. The query to get the last and the first users of the room. Seems like you need to divide your question into two ones

Comment: Basically you have M:N relationship between users and rooms (belongsToMany in terms of Sequelize).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, but not enough for my problem

Comment: First you need to define three models and show them in the question. In this case we can help you to add correct associations for them and how to get `the first and last seen of users in the room`

Comment: I wrote here as you want
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885047/for-each-10-minutes-sequelize-table-summary-for-my-table